# How to replace ISO Language codes to Language long description text in Excel (sometimes more than one language spoken per country)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to replace ISO Language codes in one Excel table with the associated Language long description title in another Excel file so that I have a complete list of languages spoken in each of the countries however there are often more than one languages per country.

Using Switzerland as an example I have the following data in my ISO language country table

```
ISO code  Language long names
de-CH   | German (Switzerland) 
fr-CH   | French (Switzerland) 
it-CH   | Italian (Switzerland)
```

In my Country overview file I have a column called 'Languages' and for Switzerland this is what appears

```
de-CH,fr-CH,it-CH
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can replace the 'de-CH,fr-CH,it-CH' data to display all of the related languages "German (Switzerland), French (Switzerland), Italian (Switzerland)' in the Language long names column on the ISO language country table?

Comment: Do you have the TEXTJOIN() Function?

Answer (score 0):

If one has Office 365, Use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),D:D,0)))
```

[image]

---

If one has 2019 then use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(E:E,N(IF({1},MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),D:D,0)))))
```

This will need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If one does not have TEXTJOIN then put this in a standard module:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

use the same formula as 2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(E:E,N(IF({1},MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),D:D,0)))))
```

Again using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]